# Django query two models and double looping

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to do the proper DRY approach in merging data from two models... I used a queryset, using a class variable as a foreign key, I can then only access one instance.  I do get a count of the number of instances:

```
nb_postal_codes = LocalModel.objects.filter(postalcode__icontains="J3L").count()
```

This gives me the total number of individual distinct postal codes lentgh of 6 filtering with the 3 first letters.  The only way I was able to merge the data, is by using two consecutive `for` loop... as in this example...

```
cp = LocalModel.objects.values_list("cp", "city_name", "latitude")
sd_cp = AddressList.objects.values_list("sd_cp", flat=True)
nb = 0


for k in sd_cp:
    for v in cp:
        if k == v[0]:
            nb += 1
            print(f"Nb: {nb} CP : {v[0]} City: {v[1]} Latitude: {v[2]}")
```

It does work OK. My question... beside using my double `for` loop... am I missing something fundamental as to the proper way of using query set and managers? they must be a better pythonic way :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do two loops. you can just use ORM queryset to achieve what you are trying in one query where a foreign key relation between models.

Please see [Django Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Comment: Printed the link document and after reading once or twice... this procedure does not seem to be a regular or conventional one... I will grind it to the bone to get a better understanding... I will get back and give you a feed back.  I previously went trought the django documentation without finding any leads, so thank you for your help.

Comment: I have past a good number of hours looking at several potential ways to do what these two loops do... a simple cartesian product of instances from both models, linking them on a common field, where one model field has unique values.  Seem simple in principle, I havent found a way to use either foreighkey models (onetomany) or ORM Generic.  I will keep on seaching. Best regards to all.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution.**  The problem was my lack of understanding of the easy link you can create between models, link that you can use to get the other variables. Foreign key most be created in the models forms.  So, no need for the double loops.

Her is the right way to do it, using double underscore added to the name of the other model key.

Here is a part of the BdSondage models:

class BdSondage(models.Model):

```
order = ['date_cre']

user = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

loccp = models.ForeignKey(BdLocCP,
    null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

loccp_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    default=1, blank=True, null=True)   

locad = models.ForeignKey(BdLocAD, 
    null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

locad_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    default=1, blank=True, null=True)
```

...

The view file using this link...

class RapportLoc(TemplateView):

```
def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_staff:

        data_users = User.objects.values_list("username", "id", named=True)

        data_tab01 = dSondage.objects.all().filter(user_id__gte="1").values_list(
            "id", "cp", "city_name", "locad__latitude",
            "locad__longitude", named=True).order_by('id')


        data_context = {
        "data_users": data_users,
        "data_tab01": data_tab01,
        }

        return render(request, "localisation/rapport_loc.html", data_context)

    else:
        return Http404("This page does not exist...")
```

Thanks to WebbyFox for the previous suggestions.